# Must I have a Facebook Timeline, if I only want to have a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

I am talking about a "Page(s)" and "Timeline(s) as defined by the following link: 
[How are Pages different from personal Timelines?](https://www.facebook.com/help/217671661585622)

I've registered a personal account (standard account; "Timeline"). I don't need a personal account. And preferred to only have my name as a "Page" due to the extra features (and due to "commercial" use).

Now, suppose that I [convert my "Timeline" to a "Page"](https://www.facebook.com/help/175644189234902/).

Would I still need a personal account ("Timeline") or is it possible to only have a "Page" account?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can no longer be without the timeline feature.

**[Here's an article I found on it.](http://techie-buzz.com/social-networking/disable-facebook-timeline.html)**